# dynamic arrays python 3

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic

List item:

```
import os
import sys
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    empty_seq=[[]]*n
    last_answer=0
    for i in range(len(queries)):
        if queries[i][0]==1:
            ans=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n)
            empty_seq[ans]=empty_seq[ans]+[queries[i][2]]
        if queries[i][0]==2:
            ans=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n)
            n=(queries[i][2]%len(empty_seq[ans]))
            last_answer=empty_seq[ans][n]
            return "{}".format(last_answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    nq = input().split()
    n = int(nq[0])
    q = int(nq[1])
    queries = []
    for _ in range(q):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
    result = dynamicArray(n, queries)
    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

here the output of the program is 7 3 and i am getting only 7
can anyone see the mistake in here 
INput

- 2 5
- 1 0 5
- 1 1 7
- 1 0 3
- 2 1 0
- 2 1 1

output
7
3

Comment: Please show the input and expected output. I'm not able to understand what is expected from this code.

Comment: What is the purpose of `((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n)`? `**` is the syntax for an exponent, not `^`, but I don't know whether you intended to use `^` because you haven't explained the purpose of the code.

Comment: Your problem is probably that the inner lists of `[[]]*n` are all the same list, so if you modify one of them you modify all. Use `[[] for _ in range(n)]` instead.